# Получить значения атрибуита при парсинге

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Здравствуйте. Использую simple html dom парсер. 
На странице есть изображения, мне нужно их получить. но дело в том, что эти изображения выводятся через css.

Вот так вот на странице они выведены:

```
<div style="background-image: url('/storage/app/uploads/public/590/d8c/d03/590d8cd0310e5578358520.jpg')" class="b-door__left js-leftDoor"></div>

<div style="background-image: url('/storage/app/uploads/public/599/152/b42/599152b42664d290873863.jpg')" class="b-door__right"></div>
```

Как мне получить ссылку на них? 
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: а какая разница ? через парсер получите все  ссылки, и в цикле добавляйте путь, начиная с домена до /storage, если конечно вы парсите один сайт (один домен)

Comment: @Arsen дело в том что ссылка на изображение вот тут: `<div style="background-image: url('/storage/app/uploads/public/590/d8c/d03/590d8cd0310e5578358520.jpg')" class="b-door__left js-leftDoor"></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы получить путь картинки из стилей, вам просто надо использовать `preg_match`. 
т.к я незнаю какой у вас код, напишу логику как получить, думаю будет понятным принцип:

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $img){
    $style = $img->style;
    preg_match('/\(([^)]+)\)/', $style, $match);
   print_r($match[1]);
}
```